# constraint dependents in array of classes

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

How can I constraint 2 variables in an array of classes, when there is a dependent between different items of the array?

```
class X;
  rand bit en;
  rand int idx;

  constraint cnst1{
     idx inside {[0:9]};
  }
endclass

class Y;
   rand X arr_x[100];

   constraint cnst2{
      ???
   }
endclass
```

I want to create cnst2 that will guarantee that:

1. each idx optional value (0-9) will be set for at least one of the arr_x[i].idx .
2. for all of the arr_x[i] that have the same value of idx, at least 1 will have en set to 1.

for example:

let's say that only the following have idx == 9:

```
arr_x[0].idx == 9;
arr_x[13].idx == 9;
arr_x[44].idx == 9;
arr_x[75].idx == 9;
arr_x[81].idx == 9;
arr_x[93].idx == 9;
```

need to guarantee that:

```
arr_x[0].en | arr_x[13].en | arr_x[44].en | arr_x[75].en | arr_x[81].en | arr_x[93].en == 1;
```

and so on for every idx value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `or` array reduction method. Also create a helper array so you can iterate from 0-9. This constraint reads: if at least one element has the value 0-9, then one of those elements has to have en set.

```
bit iterator[10];
constraint cnst2{
  foreach(iterator[i])
       arr_x.or(x) with (i ==x.idx) -> // needed if idx will not have every value 0-9
         arr_x.or(y) with (i == y.idx && y.en);
}
```

See sections *18.5.8.2 Array reduction iterative constraints* and *7.12.3 Array reduction methods* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595%5DIEEE).

Comment: i think OP also needs a loop (0..9) for every value == item.idx

Comment: @dave_59 thanks. can you please elaborate on what item.index == item.idx means?

Comment: It's a built-in member of `item`. See section *7.12.4 Iterator index querying*.

Comment: @dave_59. if i understand it correctly, it is not solving my issue.
it is looking at every arr_x[i] when i==idx, but this is not what i'm looking for.
you can see in my example that i don't have arr_x[9].idx == 9.

Comment: @dave_59 yes, i tried. i doesn't solve it as i want.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood `idx` to be an index. See corrected example.

Comment: I do not think that `arr_x.or(x) with (i ==x.idx) ->` is needed there.

Comment: I also think that `arr_x.or(x) with (i ==x.idx) ->` is not needed.
after some runs that i made, looks like the following is enough in this case:
`foreach(iterator[i])
       arr_x.or() with (i == item.idx && item.en);`
The issue is what will be when we don't have a fixed size for iterator[]?

Comment: The implication `arr_x.or(x) with (i ==x.idx) ->` is needed if _some_ values of `idx` are not used. But if _all_ values 0-9 _must_ be used, then that implication should be removed.

You are going to need some way of iterating over all the required values of `idx`